# How to use Scala Cats Validated the correct way?

Tags: scala, validation, functor, scala-cats

Following is my use case

1. I am using [Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) for validation of my config. My config file is in json.
2. I deserialize my config file to my case class `Config` using [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json) and then validate it using Cats. I am using [this](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) as a guide.
3. My motive for using Cats is to collect all errors iff present at time of validation.

My problem is the examples given in the guide, are of the type

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

def validatePerson(name: String, age: Int): ValidationResult[Person] = {
   (validateName(name),validate(age)).mapN(Person)
}
```

But in my case I already deserialized my config into my case class ( below is a sample ) and then I am passing it for validation

```
case class Config(source: List[String], dest: List[String], extra: List[String])

def vaildateConfig(config: Config): ValidationResult[Config] = {
  (validateSource(config.source), validateDestination(config.dest))
   .mapN { case _ => config }
}
```

The difference here is `mapN { case _ => config }`. As I already have a config if everything is valid I dont want to create the config anew from its members. This arises as I am passing config to validate function not it's members.

A person at my workplace told me this is not the correct way, as Cats Validated provides a way to construct an object if its members are valid. The object should not exist or should not be constructible if its members are invalid. Which makes complete sense to me.

So should I make any changes ? Is the above I'm doing acceptable ?

PS : The above Config is just an example, my real config can have other case classes as its members which themselves can depend on other case classes.

Comment: What kind of validation are you doing on these lists? If you want an additional type level enforcement, look into [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov sure Ill look into it. But is the way I described violating a good practice ?

Comment: Definitely not. It is a completely valid way of validating a parsed input which can't be enforced using type level shananigans

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One of the central goals of the kind of programming promoted by libraries like Cats is to make invalid states unrepresentable. In a perfect world, according to this philosophy, it would  be impossible to create an instance of `Config` with invalid member data (through the use of a library like [Refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined), where complex constraints can be expressed in and tracked by the type system, or simply by hiding unsafe constructors). In a slightly less perfect world, it might still be possible to construct invalid instances of `Config`, but discouraged, e.g. through the use of safe constructors (like your `validatePerson` method for `Person`).

It sounds like you're in an even less perfect world where you have instances of `Config` that may or may not contain invalid data, and you want to validate them to get "new" instances of `Config` that you know are valid. This is totally possible, and in some cases reasonable, and your `validateConfig` method is a perfectly legitimate way to solve this problem, if you're stuck in that imperfect world.

The downside, though, is that the compiler can't track the difference between the already-validated `Config` instances and the not-yet-validated ones. You'll have `Config` instances floating around in your program, and if you want to know whether they've already been validated or not, you'll have to trace through all the places they could have come from. In some contexts this might be just fine, but for large or complex programs it's not ideal.

To sum up: ideally you'd validate `Config` instances whenever they are created (possibly even making it impossible to create invalid ones), so that you don't have to remember whether any given `Config` is good or not—the type system can remember for you. If that's not possible, because of e.g. APIs or definitions you don't control, or if it just seems too burdensome for a simple use case, what you're doing with `validateConfig` is totally reasonable.

---

As a footnote, since you say above that you're interested in looking in more detail at Refined, what it provides for you in a situation like this is a way to avoid even more functions of the shape `A => ValidationResult[A]`. Right now your `validateName` method, for example, probably takes a `String` and returns a `ValidationResult[String]`. You can make exactly the same argument against this signature as I have against `Config => ValidationResult[Config]` above—once you're working with the result (by mapping a function over the `Validated` or whatever), you just have a string, and the type doesn't tell you that it's already been validated.

What Refined allows you to do is write a method like this:

```
def validateName(in: String): ValidationResult[Refined[String, SomeProperty]] = ...
```

…where `SomeProperty` might specify a minimum length, or the fact that the string matches a particular regular expression, etc. The important point is that you're not validating a `String` and returning a `String` that only *you* know something about—you're validating a `String` and returning a `String` that the *compiler* knows something about (via the `Refined[A, Prop]` wrapper).

Again, this may be (okay, probably is) overkill for your use case—you just might find it nice to know that you can push this principle (tracking validation in types) even further down through your program.

Comment: Thanks alot. Indeed an elaborate answer. Got to learn new things. Wish could give more upvotes.

Comment: I think 'newtypes' can be useful for the config use case here. Split your config into two separate case classes, like `UnvalidatedConfig` and `Config`. You can also hide the constructor of `Config` to be sure that every instance of it had to be created by the `validateConfig` method.

Comment: @AndrzejSołtysik Agreed, although I think there's a downside to proliferating types like that. If for some reason you need to package up the inputs and carry them around unvalidated for a while, though, yeah, a new `UnvalidatedConfig` is totally reasonable.