# How to separate out parsing from validation in case of versioned config using scala?

Tags: scala, validation, serialization, version, scala-cats

#### Background

I have a set of configuration JSON files that look like the following:

```
{
  "version" : 1.0,
  "startDate": 1548419535,
  "endDate": 1558419535,
  "sourceData" : [...]  // nested json inside the List.
  "destData" : [...]    // nested json inside the List.
  "extra" : ["business_type"]
}
```

There are several such config files. They are fixed and reside in my code directory only. The internal representation of each config file is given by my case class `Config`:

```
case class Attribute(name: String, mappedTo: String)

case class Data(location: String, mappings:List[Attribute])

case class Config(version: Double, startDate: Long, endDate: Long, sourceData: List[Data],
                  destData: List[Data], extra: List[String])
```

I have three classes `Provider`, `Parser` and `Validator`.

1. `Provider` has a method `getConfig(date: Long): Config`. It has to return the config satisfying `startDate <= date <= endDate` (ideally exactly one such config should be present, as `startDate` to `endDate` defines the version of config to be returned).
2. `getConfig` calls a method inside `Parser` called `parseList(jsonConfigs: List[String]): Try[List[Config]]`. What `parseList` does is try to deserialize all configs in the list, each to an instance of case class `Config`. Even if one JSON fails to deserialize `parseList` returns a `scala.util.Failure` otherwise it returns `scala.util.Success[List[Config]]`.
3. If `scala.util.Success[List[Config]]` is returned from the previous step, `getConfig` then finally calls a method inside `Validator` called `def validate(List[Config], Date): ValidationResult[Config]`, and returns it's result. As I want all errors to be accumulated I am using [Cats Validated](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) for validation. I have even asked a question about it's correct usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350436/how-to-use-scala-cats-validated-the-correct-way).
4. `validate` does the following:
    Checks if exactly ***one*** `Config` in the List, is applicable for the given 
    date (`startDate <= date <= endDate`) and then performs some validations on that `Config` (otherwise it returns an `invalidNel`). I perform some basic validations on the `Config` like checking various Lists and Strings being non empty etc. I also perform some semantic validations like checking that each String in field `extra` is present in `mappings` of each `source/dest Data` etc.

#### Question

1. The question that has troubled me for couple of last days is, my purpose for using `Cats Validated` was solely to collect all errors (and not to fail fast when encountering the first validation error). But by the time I reach `validate` method I have already done some kind of validations in `parseList` method. That is, I have already validated in`parseList` that my JSON structure is in accordance to my case class `Config`. But my `parseList` doesn't accumulate errors like my `validate` method. So if many incompatibilities between my json structure and my case class `Config` are present I'll get to know only the first. But I would like to know them all at once.
2. It  gets worse if I start adding `require` clauses like `nonEmpty` inside the case class only ( they will be invoked while construction of case class, i.e. while parsing itself), e.g.

   ```
   case class Data(location: String, mappings: List[Attribute]) {
     require(location.nonEmpty)
     require(mappings.nonEmpty)
   }
   ```

So I am not able to draw a line between my parsing and my validation functionality properly.

1. One solution I thought of was abandon the current JSON library ([lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json)) I am using and use [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson) instead. It has functionality for accumulating errors like `Cats Validated` (I got to know about it [here](https://sihil.net/cats-validated.html), goes really well with Cats `invalidNel`). I thought I would first parse JSON to play-json's JSON [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) `JsValue`, perform the structural compatible validation between `JsValue` and my `Config` using play-jsons `validate` method (it accumulates errors). If its fine read `Config` case class from `JsValue` and perform latter validations I gave examples of above, using Cats.
2. But I need to parse all config to see which one is applicable for a given date. I don't proceed if even one config fails to deserialize. If all deserialize successfully I pick the one whose `(startDate, endDate)` enclose the given date. So if I follow the solution I mentioned above, I have pushed the conversion of `List[JsValue]` to `List[Config]` to validation phase. Now if each `JsValue` in the List deserializes successfully to a `Config` instance, I can choose the applicable one, perform more validations on it and return the result. But if some `JsValue` fail to deserialize what do I do? Should I return their errors? Doesn't seem intuitive. This problem here is that I need to parse all config to see which one is applicable for a given date. And this is making it more difficult for me to mark a separation between parsing and validation phase.

How do I draw a line between parsing and validating a config in my scenario? Do I change the way I maintain versions (a version being valid from start to end date)?

PS: I am an extremely novice programmer in general. Forgive me if my question is weird. I myself never thought I would spend so much time on validation while learning Scala.

Comment: BTW: You should write `case class` with lowercase. Of course it's not a syntax error, but it's a [convention](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#classestraits).

Comment: Sure I'll keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the date intervals are contiguous, you could make your life a lot easier by having only a `startDate` in each `Config` with the `endDate` being implicit from whatever is the `startDate` of the next `Config`. That would also play well with looking up which `Config` you want for a given date: just use a `TreeMap` keyed by the date and use `treeMap.iteratorFrom(myDate).get`.

Comment: Some compilable example code would be much more helpful for understanding the issue than descriptions of the code...

Comment: Have you considered using typesafe config + pureconfig + refined types?

Answer (score 1):

```
Checks if exactly one Config in the List matches
```

If the behaviour described is the requirement, malformed JSON files are a validation error. You can change the Try[List[*]] return type to List[Try[*]] and integrate it where necessary with Validated. The documentation probably has convenient methods for working with std lib classes.

If we can take the first one that matches it's an early lunch: make the same change and just find the first one in the list that matches when looking up the config.